# Cant add non English metadata after upgrade[OJS 3.2.0.0]

Tags: mysql, ojs

Recently I have updated OJS to 3.2.0.0 , I faced a problem with add metadata (references, abstract, author names … ) contained non English characters ( ń , ł …etc. ) which disappear after click save.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

I try to changed database encoding to utf8mb4 ,

But the problem still …the code of config file ( i18n ) show below.
Any HELP Please …

[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The developers and support team for the OJS project may be your best source for help, especially if you're doing things like changing the character set used in the application's database.

Comment: The developers and support team for the OJS project ANSWER :

This is more of a database administration question than an OJS question; I’d suggest working just with your database tools (e.g. phpMyAdmin or the MySQL client) to get your character encodings consistent with your new and old databases, and only then introducing OJS (and its configuration file) into the mix. You might find guidance about this on StackOverflow.com. I suspect your old and new databases were created with different default character sets.